# SFDC Bulk API option in informatica session not working

Tags: salesforce, informatica, informatica-powercenter, salesforce-lightning

When i am loading data from oracle database to Salesforce from informatica with SFDC Bulk API checked, then no data is getting inserted into salesforce. In Workflow Monitor it is showing the successful records but when i checked in Salesforce its not getting inserted.How to bulk load to Salesforce?

Comment: What do you see in Salesforce in Setup -> Bulk Data Load Jobs? Is the job marked as completed, any errors? Bulk API essentially submits zipped CSVs of 10K records each, SF saves them and asynchronously starts to unzip, process... Might take some time. If informatica didn't mark the upload as closed (="please start processing now") or didn't periodically check results, download success/errorr files back then your status will essentially say "zips uploaded ok, no idea if they're processed yet"

Answer (score 0):

There should be some errors in your data that is the reason you are not able to see any data in your salesforce target.

While using SFDC Bulk API option the rejected data will not be written to any reject file. To know if there are any errors in your data implement below steps in order.

In target session properties check the below options.

1. Use SFDC Error File
2. Monitor Bulk jobs Until all Batches Processed.
3. Set the location of the BULK error files(you should provide a path)

After doing the above changes run the workflow if there are any errors in the data it will be moved to the reject file along with the error message which will be saved in the location you provided in step3.